# Animate color of stroke's ends using CGPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cgpath, caanimation

Quick diagrams! I'm trying to implement this:

[image: Faded]

I have this working almost 100% currently (though this is a slightly different stage of the animation):

[image: Now]

Everything looks good minus the fade effects at the end of the stroke. Is that possible using a simple `CGPath`? I'm animating `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` to get the current effect. I've tried using `CAGradientLayer` as a mask on the layer, but that adds a gradient over the entire layer, not just the ends. Overriding `drawRect` isn't possible since I'm doing this dynamically with animations.

Any thoughts about how to achieve this effect? I have no idea which direction to go.

Comment: I think I did something like what you're talking about once. My approach was to use a CAShapeLayer and then draw a CGPath and then use CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context) and CGContextClip(context) to make a clipping path. I then applied CGContextDrawLinearGradient to the context. All this was in the CAShapeLayer's drawInContext and I used a custom animatable variable so that both the clipping path and the (color) linear gradient changed together throughout the animation.

Comment: @SamuelW. Thanks for the details. I'm trying to get out of using drawInContext or any kind of manual overriding of draw functions, but that may not be possible. I'll try it out if there aren't any more ideas.

Comment: @DylanGattey were you able to fix this? I would be very interested in your solution.

Comment: I tried Sam's way but it was too slow for our needs. Still trying to make this happen, so no, no solution yet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how important opacity is and how complex the rest of the animation is, one option would be to make two blurred tail objects that [follow the ends of the path](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4) as it is animating.

[image: Paths with fuzzy tail caps]

Roundabout solution, sorry I can't think of another versatile way!